# Tabela com valor default não carregou

Tags: sql, sql-server

Criei uma tabela `GrupoDesconto`, com três campos: `Id`, `Descricao` e `MargemDesc`.

Na tabela `Revenda`, criei uma chave estrangeira (foreign key) `GrupoDescontoId` que recebe o `id` de `GrupoDesconto` e `default 1`.

Ao rodar a tabela `Revenda` já populada, observei que a coluna `GrupoDescontoId` estava `null` e não com valor `1`.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: chorar, se não preencheu ao inserir não lhe resta opção

Comment: Coloque DEFAULT na lista VALUES na posição correspondente ao campo. No seu caso: ... VALUES(valor_do Grupo_Desconto, DEFAULT)

Answer (score 0):

Se for possível remover a coluna e recriar, pode sempre fazer o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE Revenda 
DROP COLUMN GrupoDescontoId

ALTER TABLE Revenda 
ADD         GrupoDescontoId INT 
CONSTRAINT  Revenda_GrupoDescontoId_DF DEFAULT(1) NOT NULL
```

Ao atribuir o `NOT NULL` à coluna ao mesmo tempo que define a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` permite que a coluna seja preenchida, para todos os registos existentes, com o valor por omissão, neste caso o `1`.